# Theorem 6.20 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

In this video https://youtu.be/BC4ooz5L8sI . Professor proved the following theorem

> $f \in \Re$ on $[a,b]$. For $  a \leq x \leq b$, put: $F(x)  = \int_a^x f(t)dt$. If $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$  of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_o$ and $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$

Time stamp of proof, 5:00 to 14:31. Professor used mean value theorem to prove the above theorem.

**Question:** How can we use MVT on $F$, if we don’t known yet $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Comment: He is using the so-called mean-value theorem for integrals, not the mean-value theorem that you are thinking about (about derivatives).

Comment: @B.S.Thomson What is MVT for integrals?

Comment: You can find both kinds here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Thank you for clarification.

Comment: The funny part of this post is that, I didn’t know we can even proof above theorem using this(MVT for integrals) approach. Definitely learned something new.